# Carriage return issue

Tags: bash, shell, newlines

I have this in a bash script

```
DAY2="20130605"<Cr>
echo  "This is yesterday date:"$DAY2"end"
```

Why is the output the following? It seems as though there is a carriage return in `DAY2` but where is it coming from?

```
ends is yesterday date:20130605
```

Answer (score 6):

Carriage return puts the cursor back to the beginning of the line. Your output string is:

```
    This is yesterday date:20130605<Cr>end
```

Except, when the terminal hits the `<Cr>` **it returns the cursor to the beginning of the line and overwrites the characters that are there**.

In other words, "Thi" gets replaced with "end", producing:

```
    ends is yesterday date:20130605
```

To do what you appear to be trying to do your script should look something like this:

```
   variable="text"
   echo "Some sentence $variable"
```

Which will output

```
   Some sentence text
```

IF there are stray carriage returns they should show up as `^M` in `vi` (as Bruce said)

**Solution 1**

The best way to remove carriage returns or other non-printing characters is with the `tr` command with the `-d` option, which deletes any instance of a single character, with `\r` which is the escape sequence for carriage return:

```
    tr -d '\r'
```

This will remove all carriage returns. Run it on the script to remove all instances of carriage returns, then overwrite the original script file:

```
    tr -d '\r' yourscript.bash > temp
    mv temp yourscript.bash
```

**Solution 2**

or while in `vi` with the script open enter:

```
    :%s/\r//g
    :wq
```

To remove the carriage returns within the document then save it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `<Cr>` represents a carriage return, remove the carriage return from the end of the first line. Here's a one-liner to do it for you:

```
sed -i '1s/\r//' script.sh
```

To see the carriage returns in your script, run the following.

```
od -c script.sh | grep --color=yes '\r'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vi` or `vim` to look at the bash script in question. You should see any stray carriage returns as '^M' (caret, em) two-character sequences. Use hjkl to move cursor over the carriage returns, hit 'x' to delete them, then ":wq" to get out of `vi`.

My guess would be that a stray carriage return got into the file when someone moved the file to a Windows machine, edited it with Notepad or Wordpad, and then moved it back to linux.

Answer (score 1):

In shell scripts, CR is an ordinary character, not whitespace like in many other languages. That line `DAY2="20130605"<Cr>` sets `DAY2` to a 9-character string, it's equivalent to `DAY2=$'20130605\r'`. The `echo` line is equivalent to `echo  $'This is yesterday date:20130605\rend'`. The CR character (`$'\r'`) moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, thus (`¡` indicates the cursor location):

```
This is yesterday date:¡               #after printing up to date:
This is yesterday date:20130605¡       #after printing up to 20130605
¡This is yesterday date:20130605       #after printing the CR
end¡s is yesterday date:20130605       #after printing end
```

Remove the CR from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how that carriage return came to be is hard to say.

If the script was generated by another script or an application it could be a bug or intended mishap.

Most likely you or whomever edited the file has unintentionally pressed a key combination causing `CR` to be inserted.

Examples:

- `vim    :` <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>
- `emacs:` <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>
- And many others.

There are other characters that can cause trouble as well, e.g. no-break-space in code etc. This usually cause weird bugs when running scripts or compiling code.

I normally use `vim` and frequently set (have a key-combination to toggle it):

```
match Error /[^ -~\t]/
```

That is: highlight everything but `<space>` to `~` in ASCII and `tab` with `Error`, typically white on red etc.

For code files I usually have this is set on by default.

---

In the terminal carriage return normally causes the cursor to move to start of line, thus any print after it is overwriting any existing text on that line until a line feed comes along.

E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}; do
    printf "We are now at %3d%%\r" "$i"
    sleep .1
done

printf "\nAll done.\n"
```

`\r`, when using `printf` result in `<CR>` or Carriage Return.
`\n`, when using `printf` result in `<LF>` or Line Feed.